# "expected tuple but get str" when reindexing a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have a dataframe and an array, please be aware that this dataframe has only 1 column, "ds" and "code" are indices. My purpose is to get rid of all the stocks in this datafram that are not included in the array. The provided link actually does not help
Suppose this dataframe names df

```
                    dividendyield
ds       code                    
20200601 000001.SZ           1.64
         000002.SZ           3.96
         000004.SZ           0.00
         000005.SZ           0.00
         000006.SZ           3.68
...                           ...
         688516.SH           0.00
         688566.SH           0.00
         688588.SH           0.40
         688598.SH           0.00

[3837 rows x 1 columns]
```

And I have an array like this, which consists of 2000 stock codes, suppose this array names "stk_code"

```
['000001.SZ' '000002.SZ' '000004.SZ' ... '603992.SH' '603993.SH'
 '603997.SH']
```

When I use

```
df = df.reindex(stk_code)
```

It returns

```
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

Can anyone helps me with this error, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I submitted by mistake. Are you using a multi-index? How about a different approach: Create a filter expression then use .loc[] to filter. `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ds':'a a a a b c d e f f f f'.split()})` `keep = ['a','f']` `filt = [True if c in keep else False for c in df['ds'].values]` then `df.loc[filt,:]` <-- works to return as requested.

Comment: I am not using multi-indexing. The dataframe is obtained from a dataset, and I just want to reindex the dataframe with that array

Comment: The dataframe shown in the example, is infact a multiindex dataframe. Note: `[3837 rows x 1 columns]` says 1 column, which means the others are multiindex.

Comment: Indeed. I suspect this answer will be of use to you. You may need to use regex to clean the 'ds' index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022580/handling-error-typeerror-expected-tuple-got-str-loading-a-csv-to-pandas-mult

Comment: To be honest, I did not find useful information from the link you provided

Comment: `idx = pd.IndexSlice` and `df.loc[idx[:, ['stock1', 'stock2']], :]` from `question 1b` of the accepted answer works just fine to answer your question.